# Render each row with template - Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Heres my code:

```
var RowsSubView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    log.debug(this.collection);
  },

  render: function() {
    var html = RowView();
    this.setElement(html);
    return this;
  }

});


var View = BaseView.extend({

  id: 'wrapper',

  className: 'container-fluid',

  events: {
  },

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    log.debug('Initialized Queue View');
    this.opportunities = new Opportunities();

    this.opportunities.on('add', function(model){
    });

    this.opportunities.fetch({
      success: function(response, options) {
      },
      error: function(response) {
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var template = QueueView();
    this.$el.html(template);
    this.renderRowsSubView();
    return this;
  },


  renderRowsSubView: function() {
    // render rows
    this.row = new RowsSubView({collection: this.opportunities});
    this.row.render();
    this.$el.find('tbody').append(this.row.el);
  }

});
```

Heres my question:

Sorry for the noob question! I am learning Backbone and having a bit of an issue. I've looked at a bunch of tutorials/guides, but I think I've confused myself.

I am trying to create a list of items and render them in a table. I want to pass each item into my template and spit it out in the view.

I am stuck after passing my collection to my `RowsSubView`. I'm not sure how to render each object in the template. Then insert those.

PS: I am able to log `this.collection` in my `RowsSubView` and see an object with the array of items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that this might help, heres what I ended up with:

```
var RowsSubView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
  },

  render: function() {
    var html = RowView({
      opp: this.model.toJSON()
    });
    this.setElement(html);
    return this;
  }

});


var View = BaseView.extend({

  id: 'wrapper',

  className: 'container-fluid',

  events: {
  },

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'add');
    log.debug('Initialized Queue View');

    this.opportunities = new Opportunities();
    this.opportunities.on('add', this.add);

    this.fetch();
  },

  add: function(row) {
    this.row = new RowsSubView({model: row});
    this.row.render();
    $('tbody').append(this.row.el);
  },

  fetch: function() {
    this.opportunities.fetch({
      data: $.param({
        $expand: "Company"
      }),
      success: function(response, options) {
        // hide spinner
      },
      error: function(response) {
        // hide spinner
        // show error
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var template = QueueView();
    this.$el.html(template);
    return this;
  }


});

return View;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok well start with this.  Looks like there's quite a bit of cleanup that needs to be done =)

```
var RowsSubView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    log.debug(this.collection);
  },

  render: function() {
    //var html = RowView(); // Looks like you're already placing a tbody as the container
    //this.setElement(html);

    this.collection.forEach(function( model ){
      this.$el.append( RowView( model.toJSON() ) ); // Assuming RowView knows what to do with the model data
    });

    return this;
  }

});
```

Then change the `renderRowsSubView` to

```
  renderRowsSubView: function() {
    // render rows
    this.row = new RowsSubView({collection: this.opportunities});
    this.row.render();
    this.$el.find('tbody').append(this.row.$el.html());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I combined your answer with some other stuff I found.